# How to show a random friend with profile picture who uses my application

Tags: php, facebook

i want to show a random friend to user who uses my application.I have neccesarry permission to get all friends but can't show random friend(s)

Can you give me a code for this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$friends = array("Mitch", "Dave", "Charlie", "Tom"); 
$rand_keys = array_rand($friends, 1);
echo $friends[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n"; 
echo $friends[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n"; ?>
```

Comment: when i said random i meant show random friend already in users friends list :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pull back a JSON of fbuids of each friend, JSON decode it, then use array_rand to pull out a random one